# How to add a bash function to terminal in macOS

Tags: bash, macos

I want to create a bash function called "magic" that takes a string parameter and does the following:

```
magic() { git add . && git commit -m "$1" && git push; }
```

The function "magic" should be able to be called from any terminal. How can I do this?

Comment: Not sure what your problem is. If you type that into your shell you should be able to call magic "Fix bug" after that. If you add the function to - for example - .bashrc you should have it available when you start a terminal

Comment: Are you sure your shell is `bash`? Apple changed the default to `zsh` a while ago. In that case you should put the function in `.zshrc`.

Comment: @Lennart ah, thats what I was looking. Adding to .bashrc should be enough? Thank you. And yes, I use bash, not zsh, I dont quite remember why lol.

Comment: I noticed now that you are using macos so I dont know for sure, but Im willing to bet a dollar that it will work. If you have a bunch of functions it might be a good idea to put them in a separate file and source that from. bashrc.